# Google Glass User Authentication in PHP

Tags: php, android, google-glass, gdk

Good day. I'm trying to create a authentication page in my glassware as google requirement using PHP and I'm stuck for days. I followed instruction [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication) but can't make it work.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once('dbconnect.php');
    include_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    include_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_MirrorService.php';
    include_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

    function get_service_client()
    {
        global $service_client_id, $service_email, $app_name, $key_file_location, $browser_api_key;
        $client = new Google_Client();

        $client->setApplicationName("Google Glass"); // Set your application name
        $client->setClientId("CLIENT_ID");
        $client->setDeveloperKey("DEVELOPER_KEY");

        $key = file_get_contents("KEY_FILE_PATH");
        $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
                    $service_email,
                    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.thirdpartyauth'),
                    $key
                );
        $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
        return $client;
    }

    function insert_account($service,$userToken, $email)
    {
        $accountType ='info.google.glass';
        $userDataArray = array();
        $userData1 = new Google_Service_Mirror_UserData();

        $userData1->setKey('email');
        $userData1->setValue($email);

        $userDataArray[] = $userData1;
        $authTokenArray = array();
        $authToken1 = new Google_Service_Mirror_AuthToken();

        $authToken1->setAuthToken('randomtoken');
        $authToken1->setType('randomType');
        $authTokenArray[]=$authToken1;
        $postBody = new Google_Service_Mirror_Account();
        $postBody->setUserData($userDataArray);
        $postBody->setAuthTokens($authTokenArray);

        try {
            $account = $service->accounts->insert($userToken, 
                $accountType, 
                $email, 
                $postBody
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }

    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    else 
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $tempuname =isset($_POST['uname'])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']) : "";
            $temppass   = isset($_POST['pass'])  ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass'])  : "";
            $pass       = sha1($temppass);

            $uarray     = explode("/", $tempuname);

            //var_dump($uarray);
            $dbname     = $uarray[0];
            $uname      = mysql_real_escape_string($uarray[1]);
            $db         = mysql_select_db("genix_".$dbname);


                if($db && isset($uname)) 
                {
                    $sql    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$uname."' AND password = '".$pass."'");
                    if( $sql )
                    {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
                        {
                                $userToken      = $_SESSION['userToken'];
                                $service_client = get_service_client();
                                $mirrorService  = new Google_Service_Mirror($service_client);
                                insert_account($mirrorService, $userToken, $email);
                                $_SESSION['userToken']=null;
                                echo $row['facility'];
                        }
                    }
                else {
?>
<script>
    alert("Invalid Login.");
</script>
<?
    }
} else {
?>
<script>
    alert("Invalid Login.");
</script>
<?      
        }
    }
    // }
}
```

I don't received any responses nor error after submit. Can please you tell me where i went wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug this? I suggest that you check at what line/method call your code begins to not work as intended.

Comment: After debugging I found out that I'm not receiving any 'userToken' and it cause the problem. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to insert an account. If you haven't done so, you will need to go through the review process to use this function. As mentioned in the docs, you will need to have your apk uploaded to MyGlass to test/use the API.